# Migrate SharePoint online site collections to another SharePoint tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration

How can I migrate all modern and classic SharePoint sites to another SharePoint online site?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the free Microsoft SharePoint Migration tool does not support cloud to cloud migration, so you may need to use a 3rd party tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd party migration tool like ShareGate check below URL of ShareGate tool

[ShreGate Description](https://sharegate.com/sharepoint-migration)

Answer (score 0):

Mover.io is a free cloud migration tool which is recently acquired by Microsoft. it will enable migration to different platforms easily.

Answer (score 0):

The Mover.io is totally free and it's perfect for your current situation, please, go to this link https://mover.io/guides/migrating-sharepoint-to-sharepoint/#introduction